# I want it to select even numbers and tell me if it greater than a certain number. I want multiple conditions in my switch statement in my C++ program

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I want the program to read my file. I want to count all the numbers in the document that are greater than 175 and that are even using a switch statement. Or is there any better way to do it? Also wanting to know where I can get help with learning C++ since I am new to this? This is what I came up with but my program seems to not execute. This part of a bigger coding program. I want to know if it is possible to create multiple commands in the switch statement. I need help with case 0 on switch(num%2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{ //Listing all my variables 
int num;                            
double even;
int evencount = 0;
int evencountext = 0;
double big;
int bigcount = 0;
double sm;
int smcount = 0;
double odd;                 
int oddcount = 0;
double small;
double large;
double average;
double total;
int amount = 0;
string filename;

ifstream inFile;                    //Input and output data from a file    
ofstream outFile;

inFile.open("integers.dat");        //Open the integers.dat

if (!inFile)                        //Closes if the program does not exist.
{
    cout << "No File Found! Closing Program." << endl;
    return 1;
}

cout << "Welcome to Wake's Integer Processing Agency \n" << endl;        //First line of output
cout << "What is the name of your file? ";                                //Get the name of the file from user
cin >> filename;
cout << endl;

inFile >> num;                // Get the first number from the file
large = num;                // Copy the number to the large and small variables to give the number something
small = num;                // to compare them to. 

while (inFile)                //Main loop designed to grab numbers continuosly until the file ends.
{

    switch (num % 2)        //This switch divides the each number in the file by two and examines the remainder
    {
    case 0:                    // If the remainder is zero, this means the number is even

        evencount++;      // Increase the counter for even by one


       if(num >= 175)
        {evencountext++;};

        even = even + num;    // And the even number to the variable for total even numbers
        break;
    case 1:                    // If remainder is positive or negative one, this means the number is odd
    case -1:
        oddcount++;            // Increase total odd numbers by one
        odd = odd + num;    // Add the odd number to the variable for total odd numbers
    }
cout << evencountext<< endl;
cout << "The sum of the odd integers is " << odd << endl;


inFile.close();            //close the integers.dat file

return 0;                //close program
}
}
```

Comment: I meant case 0 not case 1

Comment: Instead of posting a comment you can edit your question to correct errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `if statement` remainder could be anything

```
if (num % 2 == 0){  // If the remainder is zero, this means the number is even

        evencount++;      // Increase the counter for even by one

if(num >= 175){
    evencountext++;
    even = even + num;    // And the even number to the variable for total even numbers
}
}else{  // If remainder is not zero, this means the number is odd

        oddcount++;            // Increase total odd numbers by one
        odd = odd + num;    // Add the odd number to the variable for total odd numbers
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Switches and if/else are flow control tools. If/else statements evaluate true/false, whereas switches require integer inputs and tests it against other values; uniformly.

Since you want to run multiple tests per data, I recommend that you store the data acquired into a (temporary) variable so you apply whatever multiple tests you need.

Like others have posted you should use if statements when testing for truths, and switches when testing for matches.

As for tutorials:
My default two recommended:

Tutorial spot:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_basic_syntax.htm
CPlusPlus:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/

Code relative to original post:

```
#include <iostream>//Used for c++ Standard I/O stream
#include <fstream>//Used for c++ File I/O stream

//using namespace std;//Adding this will no longer require you to type any std::
//using std::cout;//Adding this will no longer require you to type std:: in front of cout
//using std::cin;//Adding this will no longer require you to type std:: in front of cin
//using std::fstream; " " "

int main()//Main Function:
{
    //Declare and initialize fstream for input operations
    std::fstream fs ("file.txt", std::fstream::in);//Open file for reading

    //Declare integer variables and provide default values for accumulators/totals.
    int large, small, num, even = 0, odd = 0, evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0;
    //Declare boolean to test against first run; embedded initialization within loop.
    bool first = true;


    while(fs >> num) {//DATA stored into variable num.
        //Print the number out for debugging (visual reading without debugger).
        std::cout<<"The number: "<<num<<std::endl;

        //Initialize our smallest number and largest number if not done so already.
        if(first) {//Only occurs the first run
            first = false;//Disables this test from here on.
            small = large = num;
        }

        //Test if the number is larger than our largest.
        if(num > large) {
            large = num;
        }

        //Test if the number is smaller than our smallest.
        if(num < small) {
            small = num;
        }

        //Test if the number is 0 or 1. (0 and 1 are false and true, but not really).
        if(num%2 == 0) {//If even:
            ++even;//Increment counter PRE
            evenSum+=num;//Accumulate the total even values.
        }else {//Else, were assuming it is odd (without having to check again).
            odd++;//Increment counter POS; doesn't matter here
                  //but it does matter if on the stack.
            oddSum+=num;//Accumulate the total odd values.
        }
    }//The end of the while loop. It retests the loop until satisfied.
     //In a PRE loop it would leave the loop when false occurs.

    //Make sure to always close the file after you're done using it.
    fs.close();

    //Printing the data:
    std::cout<<"Number of even numbers: "<<even<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Number of odd numbers: "<<odd<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Sum of even numbers: "<<evenSum<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Sum of odd numbers: "<<oddSum<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Largest number: "<<large<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Smallest number: "<<small<<std::endl;
    //std::end produces newline and does some sub-procedure in clearing buffers.

    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
The number: 123
The number: 456
The number: 222
The number: 21
The number: 1
The number: 50
The number: 22
Number of even numbers: 4
Number of odd numbers: 3
Sum of even numbers: 750
Sum of odd numbers: 145
Largest number: 456
Smallest number: 1
```

Sample Input:

```
123 456 222
21
1

50
22 a
d
55
```